# J8583 LLLLBIN and LLLLVAR produces the different length padding result

Tags: kotlin, iso8583, j8583

LLLLVAR and LLLLBIN produces different length produced from the same input.

Tried to pass in the value "6832" into the same IsoMessage object,  however, LLLLVAR returns "**0004**6382", while LLLLBIN returns "**0008**36333832".

Sample of the source code as below:

```java
msg.setValue(60, "6832".toByteArray(Charsets.US_ASCII), IsoType.LLLLBIN, 10)//encodes to 000836333832 
msg.setValue(60, "6832", IsoType.LLLLVAR, 10) //encodes to 00046382
```

I though both should return 0004, why are both results different?

Comment: Is this Java code?

Comment: this is in kotlin

Answer (score 0):

When you encode ISO messages as text, the LxBIN fields encode their data in hex, and so the size is double what you'd expect. However, the decoder decodes the hex data and gives you a byte array when parsing.

LxVAR and LxBIN fields only have the same length when the whole message is encoded using binary formatting.

Comment: Hi Chocho, thanks for reply my message, i am trying to rework our bank posting from c# to java, i tried to change the output encoding to binary message, but the hex values are totally different, i.e: in Normal message mode, the value of 6382 encodes to (30 30 30 **38** 33 36 33 33 33 38 33 32), in binary mode, the value encodes to (00 04 36 33 38 32) , the original code that i was transforming from expects the value of (30 30 30 **34** 33 36 33 33 33 38 33 32) which looks more like the text encoding with the 4th hex as **34** instead of **38**.

Comment: What 8583 protocol are you implementing? The length field typically refers to the length  in bytes, and in rare cases the sematic length.  

1234 can be encoded in BCD as 12 34 and would have a length of two (payload bytes) or four (number of digits). Encoded in HEX as 31 32 33 34 len could only be (in my experience)  four (num of bytes == num  digits). I'm leaving aside the issue of how the length is encoded to not complicate things.

In your example you're encoding 6383 with as ASCII 36333833 not sure where the 33 padding chars are from? You need to have a look at your spec.

Comment: Hihi @a2800276, i believed what happened was 6382 already being encoded as plain text when using LLLLBIN and parsed as the byte array, i.e: the text file shows the hex value 36 33 38 32. This value was retrieved using hex editor, becoming 3336(36) 3333(33) 3338(38) and 3332(32).